# I don't know why vichuploaderBundle not upload files

Tags: symfony, vichuploaderbundle

In my Symfony 3.4 project (vich/uploader-bundle: "^1.4"), I need to upload 3 kinds of files and for two of them it's work, but for the third even if i use the same process it doesn't work...? When the form is submitted, i get this exception:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'document_name' cannot be null
```

when i dumped, i can see that my Setter "vichuploader document name" not work and can't persisted.

This is the context:

*Everythings is ok on my local version...Files are uploaded but on my production version it's doesn't work.

*I have one Entity (NoteFrais) with OneToOne relation with another Entity (Justificatif).
*The  Justificatif entity has the @vich\uploadable annotation

I followed the documentation, read many tuto, ask question on stackverflow, cleared cache and updated doctrine schema many times, tried many things...

******config.yml********

```
parameters:
    locale: fr
    app.path.logos: /uploads/logos
    app.path.imports: /uploads/imports
    app.path.documents: /uploads/documents

vich_uploader:
db_driver: orm
mappings:
    logo:
        uri_prefix: '%app.path.logos%'
        upload_destination: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web%app.path.logos%' //========IT'S WORK FINE FOR THIS ONE==========//
        namer: vich_uploader.namer_uniqid
        inject_on_load:     false
        delete_on_update:   true
        delete_on_remove:   true

    import:
        uri_prefix: '%app.path.imports%'
        upload_destination: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web%app.path.imports%' //=========IT'S WORK FINE THIS ONE=========//
        namer: vich_uploader.namer_uniqid
#           inject_on_load: true important!!
        inject_on_load:     false
        delete_on_update:   true
        delete_on_remove:   true

    document:
        uri_prefix: '%app.path.documents%'
        upload_destination: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web%app.path.documents%'
        namer: vich_uploader.namer_uniqid
 #           inject_on_load: true important!!
        inject_on_load:     false
        delete_on_update:   true
        delete_on_remove:   true
```

******JustificatifType*******

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
$builder->add('justificatifFile', FileType::class, array( //========= I TRIED WITH FILETYPE OR VICHFILETYPE =======//
    //'data_class' => null,                      //======== NOTE:USALLY I USE TO FILETYPE AND IT'S WORK FINE ==============//
    'label' => false,
    'required' => true,
    'attr' => array(
        'class' => 'NoteFraisBootstrapFileInput',
        'type' => 'file',
        'placeholder' => 'Selectionner un justificatif (jpeg, png, jpg, pdf)',
        'data-preview-file-type' => 'text',
        'data-allowed-file-extensions' => '["jpeg", "png", "jpg", "pdf"]',
    )
));
}
```

******NoteFraisType**********

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
$builder
    //=======OTHERS FIELDS===========//
    ->add('justificatif', JustificatifType::class, array(
        'required' => false));
}
```

*****Justificatif.php (Entity)*****

```
<?php

namespace MKG\MystiBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

/**
  * Justificatif
  *
  * @ORM\Table(name="justificatif")
  * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MKG\MystiBundle\Repository\JustificatifRepository")
 * @vich\Uploadable
 */
class Justificatif
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * NOTE: This is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property.
 *
 * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="document", fileNameProperty="documentName")
 *
 * @var File
 */
private $justificatifFile;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 *
 * @var string
 */
private $documentName;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 *
 * @var \DateTime
 */
private $updatedAt;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime();
}

/**
 * If manually uploading a file (i.e. not using Symfony Form) ensure an instance
 * of 'UploadedFile' is injected into this setter to trigger the  update. If this
 * bundle's configuration parameter 'inject_on_load' is set to 'true' this setter
 * must be able to accept an instance of 'File' as the bundle will inject one here
 * during Doctrine hydration.
 *
 * @param File|UploadedFile $justificatif
 */
public function setJustificatifFile(File $justificatif = null)
{
    $this->justificatifFile = $justificatif;

    if ($justificatif) {
        $this->updatedAt =  new \DateTime('now');
    }

}

/**
 * @return File|null
 */
public function getJustificatifFile()
{
    return $this->justificatifFile;
}



/**
 *
 * @param $documentName
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function setDocumentName($documentName)
{
    $this->documentName = $documentName;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return string|null
 */
public function getDocumentName()
{
    return $this->documentName;
}

/**
 * Set updatedAt
 *
 * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
 *
 * @return Justificatif
 */
public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
{
    $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get updatedAt
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getUpdatedAt()
{
    return $this->updatedAt;
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}
}
```

*******NoteFrais (Entity)*********

```
<?php

    namespace MKG\MystiBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
    use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;


/**
 * NoteFrais
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="note_frais")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MKG\MystiBundle\Repository\NoteFraisRepository")
 */
class NoteFrais
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MKG\MystiBundle\Entity\Mission", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="mission_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=true)
 */
private $mission;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MKG\MystiBundle\Entity\CodeComptable", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="compte_comptable_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL", nullable=true)
 */
private $compteComptable;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="montant_defraiement_max", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $montantDefraiementMax;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="refacturation_client", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $refacturationClient;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="total_defraiement", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $totalDefraiement;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="total_refacturation", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $totalRefacturation;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="compte_avances_et_acomptes", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $compteAvancesEtAcomptes;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="admin_current_user", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $currentUser;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="code_affaire", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $codeAffaire;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="etat", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $etat;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Justificatif", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="justificatif_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=true)
 */
private $justificatif;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="dateCreation", type="datetime")
 */
private $dateCreation;


public function __construct() {

    $this->dateCreation = new \DateTime;
    $this->etat = "0";
}



/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set montantDefraiementMax
 *
 * @param string $montantDefraiementMax
 *
 * @return NoteFrais
 */
public function setMontantDefraiementMax($montantDefraiementMax)
{
    $this->montantDefraiementMax = $montantDefraiementMax;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get montantDefraiementMax
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getMontantDefraiementMax()
{
    return $this->montantDefraiementMax;
}

/**
 * Set refacturationClient
 *
 * @param string $refacturationClient
 *
 * @return NoteFrais
 */
public function setRefacturationClient($refacturationClient)
{
    $this->refacturationClient = $refacturationClient;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get refacturationClient
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRefacturationClient()
{
    return $this->refacturationClient;
}


/**
 * Set compteAvancesEtAcomptes
 *
 * @param string $compteAvancesEtAcomptes
 *
 * @return NoteFrais
 */
public function setCompteAvancesEtAcomptes($compteAvancesEtAcomptes)
{
    $this->compteAvancesEtAcomptes = $compteAvancesEtAcomptes;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get compteAvancesEtAcomptes
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCompteAvancesEtAcomptes()
{
    return $this->compteAvancesEtAcomptes;
}

/**
 * Set currentUser
 *
 * @param string $currentUser
 *
 * @return NoteFrais
 */
public function setCurrentUser($currentUser)
{
    $this->currentUser = $currentUser;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get currentUser
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCurrentUser()
{
    return $this->currentUser;
}

/**
 * Set codeAffaire
 *
 * @param string $codeAffaire
 *
 * @return NoteFrais
 */
public function setCodeAffaire($codeAffaire)
{
    $this->codeAffaire = $codeAffaire;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get codeAffaire
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCodeAffaire()
{
    return $this->codeAffaire;
}

/**
 * Set etat
 *
 * @param string $etat
 *
 * @return NoteFrais
 */
public function setEtat($etat)
{
    $this->etat = $etat;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get etat
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getEtat()
{
    return $this->etat;
}

/**
 * Set dateCreation
 *
 * @param \DateTime $dateCreation
 *
 * @return NoteFrais
 */
public function setDateCreation($dateCreation)
{
    $this->dateCreation = $dateCreation;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get dateCreation
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getDateCreation()
{
    return $this->dateCreation;
}

/**
 * Set mission
 *
 * @param \MKG\MystiBundle\Entity\Mission $mission
 *
 * @return NoteFrais
 */
public function setMission(\MKG\MystiBundle\Entity\Mission $mission = null)
{
    $this->mission = $mission;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get mission
 *
 * @return \MKG\MystiBundle\Entity\Mission
 */
public function getMission()
{
    return $this->mission;
}

/**
 * Set compteComptable
 *
 * @param \MKG\MystiBundle\Entity\CodeComptable $compteComptable
 *
 * @return NoteFrais
 */
public function setCompteComptable(\MKG\MystiBundle\Entity\CodeComptable $compteComptable = null)
{
    $this->compteComptable = $compteComptable;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get compteComptable
 *
 * @return \MKG\MystiBundle\Entity\CodeComptable
 */
public function getCompteComptable()
{
    return $this->compteComptable;
}

/**
 * Set justificatif
 *
 * @param \MKG\MystiBundle\Entity\Justificatif $justificatif
 *
 * @return NoteFrais
 */
public function setJustificatif(\MKG\MystiBundle\Entity\Justificatif $justificatif = null)
{
    $this->justificatif = $justificatif;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return File
 */
public function getJustificatif()
{
    return $this->justificatif;
}

/**
 * Set totalDefraiement
 *
 * @param string $totalDefraiement
 *
 * @return NoteFrais
 */
public function setTotalDefraiement($totalDefraiement)
{
    $this->totalDefraiement = $totalDefraiement;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get totalDefraiement
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTotalDefraiement()
{
    return $this->totalDefraiement;
}

/**
 * Set totalRefacturation
 *
 * @param string $totalRefacturation
 *
 * @return NoteFrais
 */
public function setTotalRefacturation($totalRefacturation)
{
    $this->totalRefacturation = $totalRefacturation;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get totalRefacturation
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getTotalRefacturation()
{
    return $this->totalRefacturation;
}
}
```

********* newAction in NoteFraisController *********

```
   /**
 * Creates a new noteFrais entity.
 *
 */
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    // === RECUPERE LA MISSION
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $mission = $em->getRepository('MKGMystiBundle:Mission')->findOneBy(array('id' => $request->get('idMission')));
    $lignesNoteFrais = $em->getRepository('MKGMystiBundle:NoteFrais')->findBy(array('mission' => $mission->getId()));

    $noteFrais = new Notefrais();
    $form = $this->createForm('MKG\MystiBundle\Form\NoteFraisType', $noteFrais);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        //$noteFrais->setMission($mission);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($noteFrais);
        //dump($noteFrais);die();
        $em->flush();

        $this->addFlash('notice', 'Une ligne a été ajouté à la note de frais!');
        return $this->redirect($request->getUri());
    }

    return $this->render('@MKGMysti/Notefrais/new.html.twig', array(
        'lignesNoteFrais' => $lignesNoteFrais,
        'mission' => $mission,
        'noteFrais' => $noteFrais,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Thank you very much your time!!!!

Comment: under `setJustificatifFile` what do you get when you dump `$justificatif` !? by the way your indention above `class Justificatif` that's why the `@vich\Uploadable` not called

Comment: Thank you! The idention is correct in my original class. When form is submitted and when I dump $justificatif, I get the uploaded file (with all attributes, realName, path...) but the documentName setter is never call so I get systemically an exception.

Comment: In local every thing work great ? only in production nothing works !! maybe it's permission problème or memory size pro under php.ini config ?

Comment: Yes! In local every thing work :-). I have all permission. What do you suggest me about memory size (do you have an example?). I had already try to set more memory or increase size to uploaded files... I don't think that's the problem... Because I use exactly the same process to upload others files (like you can see in my vich_uploader config) in this project and it's work fine!

Comment: You have 3 configuations all of them not working in production orjust the last one ? II suggest to change the mapping name, to something else: instead of `ducoment` try `file_doc` and then update you entity annotation:  `@Vich\UploadableField(mapping="file_doc", fileNameProperty="documentName")`

By the way does the `$this->updatedAt =  new \DateTime('now');` is hitted ?

Comment: 2 of them work fine. I get an exception only for  the last configuration (document mapping). I have already try to change the mapping name... Unfortunately... I get always this exception...